# How to save session data in table without get expired session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am new for php with codeigniter. I have a issue about php session with codeigniter mvc framework.
When I have used table(ci-sessions) to store session data when I can not login in our site due to session expiration..

1. I have set `var $sess_table_name = 'ci_sessions';` & `var
   $sess_use_database  = TRUE;` in Session class.
2. I have also set `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` &
   `$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_sessions';` in config.php.
3. I have created table in database like-

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
   session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
   last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   user_data text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
   KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
   );

Give good solution about it.

Please help me.

Comment: Does your login work if you are not using the session table?  Also did you set your encryption key?

Comment: DO NOT change Session.php in the core system files.  Bad idea.  Use config.php to set the relevant options.

Comment: You haven't mentioned if this is your dev environment or live but try clearing your cookies or changing the name of the cookie. I found when I went live I was having issues because the cookie for my dev and live environments had the same name causing conflicts which screwed up the sessions.

Comment: this is my dev environment or live and cookies name ci_session

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Session expiration, goto application->config->config.php and set $config['sess_expiration'] equal to zero ($config['sess_expiration']=0;). That will cancel the session expiration.

Regarding saving the session in a table, make sure that your table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Of course you can add fields to it but keep that structure in mind.